# How to Group Array of Nested Objects into Multiple Arrays by Nested Value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, grouping

I am trying to convert an array to a new set of arrays by value, in this case, `id`.

**Input**

```
let array = [
  {"item": {"id": 111, "name": "item1"}, "qty": 1}, 
  {"item": {"id": 222, "name": "item2"}, "qty": 2},
  {"item": {"id": 222, "name": "item3"}, "qty": 3}
];
```

**Desired Output**

```
let newArray = [
  [{"item": {"id": 111, "name": "item1"}, "qty": 1}], 
  [{"item": {"id": 222, "name": "item2"}, "qty": 2},
   {"item": {"id": 222, "name": "item3"}, "qty": 3}]
];
```

Using a standard `groupBy` function, we can return two arrays sorted by `id`.

```
function groupItemBy(array, property) {
  var hash = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (!hash[array[i][property]]) hash[array[i][property]] = [];
    hash[array[i][property]].push(array[i]);
  }
  return hash;
}
```

However, when trying to map these to new arrays the nested `qty` data is lost.

```
function parse() {
  let tmp = Object.values(groupItemBy(array.map(el => el.item), "id"));

  tmp.forEach(item => {
    console.log(item);
    // do something with each item in array
  })
}
```

**Actual Output**

```
let newArray = [
  [{{"id": 111, "name": "item1"}], 
  [{"id": 222, "name": "item2"},
   {"id": 222, "name": "item3"}]
];
```

How can the integrity of the associated data be maintained while grouping the original array into an array of sorted arrays?

Comment: You should really try lodash for this kind of stuff: `_.values(_.groupBy(array, 'item.id'))`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For this to work you will have to somehow tell the function where the key property is located. One can imagine very complex, nested objects, and several might have the same property names, so it even could lead to ambiguity if there is no such specification.

One way to tackle this is to make the function aware of dot-separated properties (in one string) -- a kind of "path". In your case that would be `item.id`. With that information the function can know where to look for the `id` value (in the nested object `item`).

Obviously the function would split that string by those dots. It can then perform a `reduce` on the resulting array of property names to locate the key value for each object in the array.

Here is how that could look:

```js
let cart = [{"item": {"id": 111,"name": "item1", }, "qty": 10,}, {"item": {"id": 222,"name": "item2"},"qty": 1}, {"item": {"id": 222,"name": "item3"},"qty": 1,}];

function groupItemBy(array, property) {
    var hash = {},
        props = property.split('.');
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var key = props.reduce(function(acc, prop) {
            return acc && acc[prop];
        }, array[i]);
        if (!hash[key]) hash[key] = [];
        hash[key].push(array[i]);
    }
    return hash;
}

let grouped = Object.values(groupItemBy(cart, 'item.id'));
console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `reduce` to check, if you already seen current key, and if not - create it with empry array as a value, and push there the whole current object. Then you need to get values on result, and you good to go.

```
Object.values(arr.reduce((result, obj) => {
  (result[obj.item.id] || (result[obj.item.id] = [])).push(obj);
  return result;
}, {}));
```

Or, you can use Lodash and `groupBy`, then you'll have this:

```
Object.values(_.groupBy(arr, "item.id")));
```

Play with this bin to see the result in console - https://codesandbox.io/s/qx14372v74

Answer (score 1):

### Summary

```
const transform = (array) => Object.values(array.reduce(
  (all, curr) => {
    const key = curr.item.id;
    (all[key] || (all[key] = [])).push(curr);
    return all;
  }, {}
))
```

### Using a Library

Using [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com) (disclaimer: I'm a Ramda author), I would do it like this, without thinking twice:

```
const transform = compose(values, groupBy(path(['item', 'id'])))
const results = transform(array)
```

### Converting Library Code

Assuming we wouldn't want to include a library for this problem, I would work from that solution step-by-step.  We first need to remove the `compose`, which is easy with just two functions.  We first add an explicit parameter:

```
const transform = (array) => compose(values, groupBy(path(['item', 'id'])))(array),
```

and then wrap the two calls in the `compose`:

```
const transform = (array) => Object.values(groupBy(path(['item', 'id']), array))
```

Then we can easily replace `path(['item', 'id'])` with `obj => obj.item.id`.  Note that we lose a little safety here.  We could add an exception if there is no `item` property.  But doing it safely would add a lot more machinery.

```
const transform = (array) => Object.values(groupBy(obj => obj.item.id, array))
```

Then we could write a simple version of `groupBy`:

```
const groupBy = (fn) => (list) => list.reduce(
  (all, curr) => {
    const key = fn(curr);
    (all[key] || (all[key] = [])).push(curr);
    return all;
  },
  {}
)
```

and replace the Ramda `groupBy` with that, folding in our simple `path` replacement with the values we prefer:

```
const transform = (array) => Object.values(array.reduce(
  (all, curr) => {
    const key = (obj => obj.item.id)(curr);
    (all[key] || (all[key] = [])).push(curr);
    return all;
  }, {}
))
```

And with a little simplification, we get

```js
const transform = (array) => Object.values(array.reduce(
  (all, curr) => {
    const key = curr.item.id;
    (all[key] || (all[key] = [])).push(curr);
    return all;
  }, {}
))

const array = [{"item": {"id": 111, "name": "item1"}, "qty": 1}, {"item": {"id": 222, "name": "item2"}, "qty": 2}, {"item": {"id": 222, "name": "item3"}, "qty": 3}];

console.log(transform(array));
```

### Building our own Mini-Library

Alternatively, we could actually create equivalents of those Ramda function, as they could be useful in all sorts of ways:

```js
const groupBy = (fn) => (list) => list.reduce(
  (all, curr) => {
    const key = fn(curr);
    (all[key] || (all[key] = [])).push(curr);
    return all;
  },
  {}
)
const values = obj => Object.values(obj);
const pipe = (f1, ...fns) => (...args) => {
  return fns.reduce((res, fn) => fn(res), f1.apply(null, args));
};
const path = (nodes) => (obj) => nodes.reduce((o, node) => o[node], obj)


const transform = pipe(groupBy(path(['item', 'id'])), values)

const array = [{"item": {"id": 111, "name": "item1"}, "qty": 1}, {"item": {"id": 222, "name": "item2"}, "qty": 2}, {"item": {"id": 222, "name": "item3"}, "qty": 3}]

console.log(transform(array))
```

(Note that I switched from `compose` to `pipe`, simply because it is easier to implement quickly.  They have the same behavior but take their lists of functions in opposite order.)