# Expansion Panel Group header and iterate child object

Tags: javascript, css, angular, bootstrap-4

```
"fixtures" : 
    [{"hometeam" : Atletico,
    "awayteam" : Barca,
    "Kickoff: 11:00 ,
    "Tournament" : {"tournamentId" : 1001, "Name" : European Cup },

    {"hometeam" : Liverpool,
    "awayteam" : Real Madrid,
    "Kickoff: 20:00,
    "Tournament" : {"tournamentId" : 1001, "Name" : European Cup},

    {"hometeam" : brasil,"awayteam" : france,"Kickoff: 2:00 am,
    "Tournament" : { "tournamentId" : 1002, "Name" : World cup }]
```

Given the above structure I would like to use Angular Expansion Panel to 
show the tournament name in the  
and the list of fixtures when the panel expand.
This will have to group by the competition name on the header.

Please see in expected result

```
<mat-expansion-panel  *ngFor="let item of fixtures">
<mat-expansion-panel-header style="display:flex" class="mat-row">
<span>{{item.tournament.Name}}</span>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Expected result:

```
European Cup   -- when expand must show as below
1 - Atletico V/s Barca
    Kickoff : 11:00 am 
2 - Liverpool V/s Real Madrid
    Kickoff : 20:00

World Cup
1 - brasil V/s france
    kickoff : 2:00 am
```

When Collapse will only show

```
European Cup
World Cup
```

Comment: not a valid JSON, please provide a valid JSON

Comment: Might be you need to re-format your JSON which will be easy to achieve expected output

Comment: [
 {
  "id": "0001",
  "type": "donut",
  "name": "Cake",
  "ppu": 0.55,
  "batters":
   {
    "batter":
     [
      { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" }
     ]
   }

 },
 {
  "id": "0002",
  "type": "donut",
  "name": "Raised",
  "ppu": 0.55,
  "batters":
   {
    "batter":
     [
      { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" }
     ]
   }
 }
]

Comment: I would like this to be grouped by donut

Comment: Check this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f86jqn

Comment: Check the posted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below Group By Function ([`#copied`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48855499/7124761)):

```
groupItemBy(array, property) {
    var hash = {},
      props = property.split('.');
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      var key = props.reduce(function (acc, prop) {
        return acc && acc[prop];
      }, array[i]);
      if (!hash[key]) hash[key] = [];
      hash[key].push(array[i]);
    }
    return hash;
}
```

and use it as:

```
formatedArray : any[] = [];

this.formatedArray = Object.values(this.groupItemBy(this.fixtures, 'Tournament.Name'));
```

[`Working_Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f86jqn)